# how to create a jar file of a maven project in neatbeans

Tags: java, maven

I have a maven project that i finished developing and now am having a hard time on packaging and deploying the software for use.

If I create a new project (Java Application) it does show the packaging option and then I can easily create a jar file, but the maven project that I am working on does not work like this.

Please any suggestion on a way to create jar file out of my maven project will be great.
This is my pom file

```
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <mainClass>com.inventory.gui.InventoryApp</mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
                <descriptorRefs>
                    <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                </descriptorRefs>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
</properties>
```

Comment: use maven to package your project:
1. install maven
2.from project base directory, execute: mvn clean package

Answer (score 0):

1. Add the following to pom file
2. Replace **MAIN CLASS** with your main class
3. Rebuild your JAR and check

try to add **maven-assembly-plugin** as follows.

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <descriptorRefs>
            <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
        </descriptorRefs>
        <archive>
            <manifest>
                <mainClass>**MAIN CLASS**</mainClass>
            </manifest>
        </archive>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>make-assembly</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>                         
                <goal>single</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Comment: I just posted my pom file, zero results

Comment: Why didn´t you added the execution part?   <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>make-assembly</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>                         
                <goal>single</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>